# Npgsql C# problem with App.Config PostgreSQL Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Just made new Console App for test database. It was working fine every time in my projects in past, but now i have problem which i can't solve. I created App.config manualy (VStudio didn't generate it). I used settings from [This link](https://schneide.blog/2017/09/26/using-postgresql-with-entity-framework/). In past i was working with MSSql, and SQLite and it works fine. But my try with Postgresql not working. Can you tell me what should i do?

My *App.config* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql"
         type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
           invariant="Npgsql"
           description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql"
           support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDatabaseConnectionString"
         connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=photo_service;Port=5432;Password=postgres;User Id=postgres"
         providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

My *AppDatabase:Context* and *class User*

```
class AppDatabase : DbContext
{
    private readonly string schema;
    public AppDatabase(string schema) : base("AppDatabaseConnectionString")
    {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
         builder.HasDefaultSchema(this.schema);
         base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }


    }

class User
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
 }
```

And finally my initialization of postgres query:

```
var db = new AppDatabase("Users");
using (var database = new AppDatabase("User"))
    {
        var users = database.Users.First(user => user.name == "Blah blah blah");
    }
```

it all gives me error:

```
Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is 
installed or registered in the application config.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved. I created 
`ConsoleApp .NET Framework`
instead
`ConsoleApp .NET Core`
as github says

> EF6 does not (yet) run on .NET Core--see